# How to obtain the content of the field "addr_tag_link" and "addr_tag" without using the api of blockchain.info?

Tags: address, java

This is an output item of JSON result obtained by the API of blockchain.info:

```
        {
         "addr_tag_link":"https:\/\/bitcointalk.org\/index.php?action=profile;u=47767",
         "addr_tag":"DoubleIcaras",
         "spent":true,
         "tx_index":2751327,
         "type":0,
         "addr":"1F6MCoBMwmfpT5fruvCUjirFEybhLe5c1C",
         "value":100000,
         "n":250,
         "script":"76a9149a94b4a9d14807579aa4f9bd3d6a812adb6f7fbf88ac"
      }
```

Is it possible to obtain the content of the field "addr_tag_link" and "addr_tag" in java without using the API of blockchain.info (such as with bitcoinj)?

Answer (score 1):

No, the `addr_tags` are specific to blockchain.info - they are not kept on the Bitcoin blockchain, but rather on blockchain.info's servers.

Comment: So there is no other ways to obtain such information?